# Dynamically Add and remove Markers (L.MarkerCluster)

Tags: jquery, plugins, leaflet, mapping

I'm having difficulties on removing existing markers on the map.

Initially the map should look like this

[image]

but If I pick a smaller circle like this, the markers are still there.
[image]

Is there a way to refresh/remove all the existing markers on the map?

Here's the snippet of my code

```
var markers; 
 var theMarker = L.marker(latlng,{icon: iconURL})
                .openPopup()
                .on('click',onClick);   

function onClick(event) {
                event.target.bindPopup(content);
    }   
if (markers){
 map.removeLayer(markers);
 }                          
markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
markers.addLayer(theMarker);
map.addLayer(markers);`
```

it seems like map.removeLayer didn't work at all.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Could you please add a fiddle so that I can help fix this problem? Cheers

Comment: What exactly should your code do? In the code you share, `removeLayer` will not be called at all.

Comment: Want I wanted to achieve is to dynamically remove the existing markers on the map and completely replace them with a new one whenever there's a request. The data is coming from the database.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed.

I just put markers in a LayerGroup and delete the layer every time the AJAX request is being called.

Thanks for all the help!